# Why, on StackExchange sites, is the post title on the question page a link to itself?

Tags: seo, usability

It may look like a question for meta.stackoverflow.com, but I'd like to know if this decision has something to do with SEO or if this improve the user experience somehow.

It's a link to the same page you are, so I don't see the usefulness of this.

On Quora, for exemple, on the question page, the question title is not a link.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is no SEO benefit as self-links are ignored by the PageRank algorithm. However, this is often done (on other sites and blog posts too) for a couple of reasons:

1. It allows you to refresh the page quickly, and in some instances without the warning that you are resubmitting postdata.
2. Similarly you can re-request the page from scratch, useful if you for example posted a comment with AJAX, navigated to another page, clicked back and the browser showed the old page.
3. It provides access to the true, canonical URL, without query string parameters and the like. And quick access to right click and copy the link address, eg for sharing.

Comment: +1 for the third point - I think the Canonical URL is the main benefit for websites.

Comment: Resubmitting post data can be easily solved by doing a redirect after the POST request.

Comment: *There is no SEO benefit as self-links are ignored by the PageRank algorithm* - citation needed

Comment: @Sfisioza if linking a page to itself increased its PageRank then the entire algorithm would implode.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really use the {link} to get the permalink of a question (I get it from the URL), and usually by this time I have already posted or commented something and the URL looks now like this:

```
http://example.com/123123#annoyingCommentId666
```

Clicking the title will clean it and make it ready to be copied and shared with no worries of linking to a comment:

```
http://example.com/123123
```

That is really useful for me, I do this more often than you will think

Comment: I think DisgruntledGoat covered this in point #3, but still, your example does help clarify this point. +1